# Magento - getting the available filters for a category in top navigation

Tags: php, magento

I am developing with Magento 1.6.2.

I want to display a drop down containg filters (colour, size etc) from my categories in my top navigation bar.

So far (in /app/design/fontend/package/theme/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml) I have:

```
<ul>    
<?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()); ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()); ?></a>
    <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
    <div>
            <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
            <dl>
            <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </dl>
            <?php endforeach; ?>        
    </div>          
</li>
<?php endforeach ?> 
</ul>
```

$this->getFilters() is not returning anything.
How can I get the filters in the content of the category?

Comment: Are the categories set to Anchor = Yes?

Comment: its not imposibble that you thought! Think about that, you visiting a cms page, the drop down visible in there as well but without content. The reason is that, there is no category collection in cms pages. Same aspect for navigation section. There is no product collection in navigation section therefore product attributes will not shown in drop-down.

Comment: The anchor is indeed set to yes

Answer (score 1):

`catalog/navigation/top.phtml` uses `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` and it doesn't implement method `getFilter()` unless you've added such... This block is responsible for displaying Top Navigation Menu/

I think that you're looking for [Layered Navigation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-does-layered-navigation-work) which is used in Category View Toolbar and is responsible for category filters.